# Finding the CDF

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X \sim {\rm uniform}[0,1]$ and  $Y=\ln(X)$. Find the cdf, $F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y)$, of $Y$, and specify the range of values for $y$.

I use substitution and do the following:

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(\ln(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq e^y)$

Then,

$P(X\leq e^y)$=$\begin{cases}0 & e^y<0 \\ e^y & 0\leq e^y \leq 1 \\ 1 & e^y > 1\end{cases}$

Is this correct? If not, is there something I am simply overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: The values of $\ln(x)$ are supported on $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: I am slightly confused by the comment, can you offer another hint? Is this true only for $y>0$?

Comment: If $0\le X \le 1$, then $\ln(x) \le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $e^y < 0$ never inheres, so you can discard it.  So you have
$$ P(X\le y) = \cases{e^y & if $y < 0$\cr 1 & if $y \ge 0$.}$$

Comment: Seems so ridiculous that I did not see that before. Thank you.

Comment: It's largely a presentation thing.